# How to check if an option has a default value in Vim?

Tags: vim, configuration

I want to `set directory` in my `.vimrc` **only** if it hasn't been changed in the system-wide vimrc file. Is there any concise way to check if an option has a default value?

Something like:

```
if is_default(&directory)
   set directory^=~/path/to/dir//
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any simple way to get the default for an option. The only way I know is to save the current value, reset the option to default, save the default and restore original value.

```
function! IsDefault(option)
    " Get the current value
    exe "let l:save_value = &" . a:option
    " Reset to default
    exe "set " . a:option . "&"
    " Get the default value
    exe "let l:save_default = &" . a:option
    " Restore original value
    exe "set " . a:option . "=" . l:save_value
    return l:save_value == l:save_default
endfunction
```

Additional subproblem is that restoration for string/numeric options and boolean options are different — for a boolean option the restoration must be

```
    if l:save_value
        exe "set " . a:option
    else
        exe "set no" . a:option
    endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the following function:

```
function! Is_default(opt)                                                       
  execute "let tmp = &".a:opt                                                   
  redir => l:default                                                            
  execute "set ".a:opt."&"                                                      
  silent execute "echo &".a:opt                                                 
  redir end                                                                     
  if tmp==l:default[1:]                                                         
    return 1                                                                    
  else                                                                          
    execute "set ".a:opt."=".tmp                                                
    return 0                                                                    
  endif                                                                         
endfunction
```

Now you could check if `formatoptions` has default value:

```
if Is_default("fo")                                                             
  echo "Option has default value"                                                                  
endif
```